# How to ask for userinput and do something else at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to make a simple command line irc client.
I basically want to receive and send messages. The problem is that in the code below the program waits until some input is given, as expected. So my question is how would you receive the buffer and userinput at the same time.

```
def main():
    connect(server)
    join_channel(channel)  

    while True:                                                                                
        buffer=irc.recv(2040).decode('utf-8')                                                                   
        buffer = buffer.strip('\n\r')
        print(buffer)
        
        if buffer.find('PING') != -1:                                                                             
            irc.send(('PONG ' + buffer.split() [1] + '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
                                                                                                                                    
        userInput = input("Type something")

        if userinput == "!hi"
            irc.send(('PRIVMSG '+channel+' :Hello'! \r\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

I tried with multiprocessing but failed. Maybe somebody could show/or link me some example code how to implement something like that. Thank you!

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time to write up a complete example/answer here, but this is a case where you would want to use threading.  As an example: one thread would handle receiving from the buffer and printing the incoming messages, while the other thread would wait for user input and then send it.

Comment: But acording to my understanding you would "join" the threads in order to return to the main thread. So in my usecase the program would wait again for the userinput. Or would I just not join the thread with the user input?

Comment: You would probably want to keep the user input in the Main thread, and put the message receiving into a daemon thread.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok after further investigation got it working. Probably not the best way to implement it, so any improvements are welcome.**

```
def read_buffer():                                                                          
    buffer=irc.recv(2040).decode('utf-8')                                                       
    buffer = buffer.strip('\n\r')
    print(buffer)
              
    if buffer.find('PING') != -1:                                                                    
        irc.send(('PONG ' + buffer.split() [1] + '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))    

def check_write_input():
    while True:
        userInput = input("~$")
        irc.send(('PRIVMSG '+channel+ ' :' +userInput + '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=check_write_input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect(server)
    join_channel(channel)

    time.sleep(1)

    t1.start()

    while True:
        read_buffer()
        t1.join(timeout=0.1)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have a call to `t1.join(timeout=0.1)`. This will never successfully join the `t1` thread but will cause you to delay calling `read_buffer` again for .1 seconds. If you want to concurrently read and write I don't see why you would not want to get rid of this call altogether.